# Cannot doctest two files in the same directory across Python 2 and 3 when importing all

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two files, `core.py` and `extend.py`, in a single directory named `module`. The directory also contains an empty file named `__init__.py`.

```
module/
  __init__.py
  core.py
  extend.py
```

The `core` module just defines a hundred constants (and does not import anything).

The `extend` module extends the `core` module, by importing everything from it, then adding some extra stuff.

The end user will only ever import from `extend`.

Both `core.py` and `extend.py` contain doctests.

I need to write an import statement in `extend.py` that imports everything from `core`, that does not throw an exception when the modules are executed as scripts (to run the doctests). I can only get it to work for Python 2 or 3, but not both.

I've tried starting `extend.py` with `from core import *` and `from .core import *`. Python 2 is fine, but Python 3 will not allow me to doctest `extend.py` in the first case, and not allow the user to import `extend` in the second.

I am happy to restructure the directory tree, or to run the doctests differently, but do not understand why it doesn't work.